# How to bind dynamic Check boxes value using ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to put the values of dynamic checkboxes (not boolean true and false) in the form of array using 'ng-model' in a similar way as is done using 'name' attribute. This array is now put into a JSON object.

```
<td>
   <span ng-repeat="operation in operations_publish">
            <input type="checkbox" name="operations" ng-model="operations" value="{{operation}}"/>
            {{operation}}
   </span>
</td>
```

Following is my function to post the JSON object:

```
$scope.send = function() {
    console.log("test");
    var dataObj = {
        "operationType" : $scope.operationType,
        "conceptModelID" : $scope.conceptID,
        "requestor" : $scope.requestor,
        "status" : "new",
        "requestDateTime" : null,
        "lastExecutedDateTime" : null,
        "completedDateTime" : null,
        "instructions" : $scope.operations

    };
    console.log(dataObj);
    console.log(dataObj.instructions);
    var response = $http.post('PostService', dataObj);
    response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.responseData = data;
    });
    response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
            data : data
        }));
    });
```

But 'dataObj.instructions' is undefined when I run the code. Please suggest whether it is the right way of doing it and what am I missing here.

Comment: You have `ng-model="operations"` however `operation` as your iterator in the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind each input to a different value. Currently all of them are bound to the field `operations` in the scope via `ng-model="operations"`.

I suggest you create an array `operations` in your controller like this:

```
$scope.operations = new Array($scope.operations_publish.length);
```

Then you can bind the checkboxes to the respective index in this array:

```
<span ng-repeat="operation in operations_publish">
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="operations"
           ng-model="operations[$index]"
           value="{{operation}}"/>
    {{operation}}
</span>
```

This will give you an array with `true` at all checked indexes. If you then want the selected values as strings in an array, you can collect them like this:

```
function getSelected() {
    return $scope.operations_publish.filter(function (x,i) {
        return $scope.operations[i]
    });
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wrxa79n/1/) for the complete code.

Comment: Thanks. It answered my question and I am getting the values in the array now. However, when I am trying to post the JSON object to my spring controller, I am getting the error: 400(Bad Request). Any idea what could have caused that?

Comment: No, sorry, that is really hard to tell without further information. Did you examine the request in your browser? I mean, get the actual URL that was requested and the HTTP parameters?

Answer (score 1):

did you try ?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cbValues[$index]"
    ng-repeat="value in cbValues track by $index" />
```

Works for me :
http://plnkr.co/edit/s0rZiMeL4NvpFZ3C9CIL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

According to your example listed there, you have bound your `ng-model` to the expression `operations`, however you need to be binding it to the individual iterator `operation` (from) `ng-repeat="operation in operations_publish"`.

You can then set that data in your dataLog object:

```
var dataObj = {
    "operationType" : $scope.operationType,
    "conceptModelID" : $scope.conceptID,
    "requestor" : $scope.requestor,
    "status" : "new",
    "requestDateTime" : null,
    "lastExecutedDateTime" : null,
    "completedDateTime" : null,
    "instructions" : $scope.operations_publish
};
```

Data binding by default in angular are multi-directional therefore:

1. `operations_publish` => bound to row via iterator `operation`
2. `operation` => bound to checkbox value via `ng-model`
3. When the value of the checkbox changes, you change the variable it was bound to, and the collection that variable iterated from.