# How to know checkbox checked or not inside ng-repeat and how to use ng-model for checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below json will use in `ng-repeat.

```
[
  {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryName": "Men",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": 1,
        "subCategoryName": "Footwear"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": 3,
        "subCategoryName": "Cloths"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "categoryName": "Women",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": 2,
        "subCategoryName": "Footwear"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 3,
    "categoryName": "Kids",
    "subCategory": []
  }
]
```

Below code have two `ng-repeat` and showing data of above json.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="cat in catSubCat">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories" id="category_{{cat.categoryId}}" ng-model="categoryChk" ng-change="categoryCheckBox(cat.categoryId, $index)" readonly><span class="gap">{{cat.categoryName}}</span>
        </label>
        <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="subCat in cat.subCategory">
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="subcategories" id="sub_category_{{subCat.subCategoryId}}" ng-model="subCategoryChk" ng-change="subCategoryCheckBox(cat.categoryId, subCat.subCategoryId, $index)"><span class="gap">{{subCat.subCategoryName}}</span></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this code I am trying to console the models to check whether the checkbox are checked or not

```
$scope.subCategoryCheckBox = function(catId, subId, index) {
    console.log($scope.subCategoryChk);
}

$scope.categoryCheckBox = function(catId, index) {
    console.log($scope.categoryChk);
}
```

I am trying to check whether the checkbox are checked or not inside `$scope.subCategoryCheckBox()` and `$scope.categoryCheckBox()` by printing model in console. But it is showing `undefined` in console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind dynamic Check boxes value using ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006596/how-to-bind-dynamic-check-boxes-value-using-ng-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code:

- Make the vars `categoryChk` and `subCategoryChk` **objects** (it could be arrays too), like this:

  `$scope.categoryChk = {};`
  `$scope.subCategoryChk = {};`
- Change the assignation to the model in the html in order to **match** with the previously created **objects**. For categories, from this: `ng-model="categoryChk"` to this: `ng-model="categoryChk[cat.categoryId]"` ... and for the subcategories, from this: `model="subCategoryChk"` to this `model="subCategoryChk[subCat.subCategoryId]"`.
- Now in the functions you can access the model throught the index passes as argument like this:

  ```
  $scope.subCategoryCheckBox = function(catId, subId, index) {
    console.log($scope.subCategoryChk[subId]);
  }

  $scope.categoryCheckBox = function(catId, index) {
    console.log($scope.categoryChk[catId]);
  }
  ```

See working snippet and explanation below.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', ctrl);

  function ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.catSubCat = [{
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "Men",
        "subCategory": [{
            "subCategoryId": 1,
            "subCategoryName": "Footwear"
          },
          {
            "subCategoryId": 3,
            "subCategoryName": "Cloths"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "Women",
        "subCategory": [{
          "subCategoryId": 2,
          "subCategoryName": "Footwear"
        }]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 3,
        "categoryName": "Kids",
        "subCategory": []
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.categoryChk = {};
    $scope.subCategoryChk = {};

    $scope.subCategoryCheckBox = function(catId, subId, index) {
      console.log($scope.subCategoryChk[subId]);
    }

    $scope.categoryCheckBox = function(catId, index) {
      console.log($scope.categoryChk[catId]);
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="cat in catSubCat">
    <li>
      <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories" id="category_{{cat.categoryId}}" ng-model="categoryChk[cat.categoryId]" ng-change="categoryCheckBox(cat.categoryId, $index)" readonly><span class="gap">{{cat.categoryName}}</span>
        </label>
      <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="subCat in cat.subCategory">
        <li>
          <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="subcategories" id="sub_category_{{subCat.subCategoryId}}" ng-model="subCategoryChk[subCat.subCategoryId]" ng-change="subCategoryCheckBox(cat.categoryId, subCat.subCategoryId, $index)"><span class="gap">{{subCat.subCategoryName}}</span></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

The thing is, when you assign `categoryChk` and `subCategoryChk` to your model it assigns the same `ng-model` to all categories and subcategories respectively. This is not the way you want it to work, you need to assign a different model for every check (when you do `categoryChk[cat.categoryId]`, you create on the fly an attribute in `categoryChk` for that model, and so on for every category in the `ng-repeat`, this is how you want it to work)

Comment: if you click on Footwear it will check in two section, can you tell me how to resolve this

Comment: Yes. Change $index for `subCat.subCategoryId` and `cat.categoryId` respectively in the view and in the functions, do not use the `index`, use instead `subId` and `catId` respectively. See my answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You may directly send the model to your function as shown in the below code, also you can check with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/37LRX5bVZMrR0thhIdRm) link for your example scenario.

Template:

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="categories" id="category_{{cat.categoryId}}" 
              ng-model="categoryChk" ng-change="categoryCheckBox(cat.categoryId, $index, categoryChk)" 
              readonly><span class="gap">{{cat.categoryName}}</span>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.categoryCheckBox = function(catId, index, selectedCat) {
      console.log(selectedCat);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to mantain these objects clean, you can add in any cat/subcat the checked property like as you can see here

```
<input type="checkbox" name="categories" id="category_{{cat.categoryId}}" ng-model="cat.categoryChk" ng-change="categoryCheckBox(cat, $index)" readonly><span class="gap">{{cat.categoryName}}</span>
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16200/