# Setting ng-model within ng-repeat using ng-change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

How do I set a result in a ng-model that is inside an ng-repeat?

Example containing `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key,boleta) in boletas track by $index">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <label for="">NUMBER </label>              
    <select name='bills[{{key}}][number]' class="form-control" 
      ng-change='changeBoletas()' ng-model='model.numberBoleta'>
      <option ng-repeat="(number, x) in model.boletas">{{number}}</option>
    </select>    
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="">Comisión </label>
    <input name='bills[{{key}}][runt]' type="number" 
      class="form-control comision-{{key}}" 
      ng-model='boleta[$index].comision' 
      ng-change='dataBoleta()'>                
    <td>
      <div ng-show='true' ng-if="status=='applied'" 
        data-ng-click="removeItemBoletas($index)">
        <i class="fa fa-times color3"></i>
      </div>     
    </td>          
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
$scope.changeBoletas = function() {
    $scope.boleta=[];
    $scope.boleta[0].comision=123; 
}
```

The error that occurs is:

> TypeError: Can not set property 'comision' of undefined

https://jsfiddle.net/05er7rk5/18/

I would like every time you choose an option of the select the mimes autocomplete the ng-model.

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.boleta[0] = { comision: 123 }`? since `boleta` array is still empty and you are calling a value of it at index `0` which obviously will give you `undefined`

Comment: The undefined is no longer output but the ng-model is not completed

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide a code snippet for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437107/how-to-know-checkbox-checked-or-not-inside-ng-repeat-and-how-to-use-ng-model-for check this url

Comment: Sure https://jsfiddle.net/05er7rk5/18/

Answer (score 0):

The error has been occurred as you are trying to access `$scope.boleta[0]` which has no value. In the code, `$scope.boleta.push({comision:123})` ,I created and added an element.
Now if you access, `$scope.boleta[0].comision = 123;`, then the error will disappear.

Please use like the following code:

```
$scope.changeBoletas=function(){
    $scope.boleta=[];
    $scope.boleta.push({comision:123}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Can not set property 'comision' of undefined

As `$scope.boleta` is declared as an empty array `[]`. Hence, there is no object exist in the array with `comision` property.

If you are trying to access the object into an array you can do like this **:**

```js
var boleta = [];
boleta[0] = { comision: 123 };

console.log(boleta);
```

Comment: But I can not make the result that I have executed can be visualized in the ng-model of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The error was already solved. The problem was due to the declaration of the NG-model that was inside the NG-REPEAT. In this case, the MODEL of the NG REPEAT should be called so that it can recognize it and, above all, it would not come out undefined

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key,boleta) in boletas track by $index">

$scope.changeBoletas = function(varDato) {
      $scope.boletas[varDato].comision=123; 
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awilchesl/fwp5rfvp/12/